# How can you close a dropdown by clicking anywhere on the page in vue 3 js

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, dropdown, tailwind-css

I'm using vue 3 js along with tailwind. My dropdown works right now, but to close it I have to click on the dropdown. I would like the ability to click anywhere on the page and the dropdown close. Originally tailwind was having me using Popover's and PopoverButton's but that affected the modal that pops up after selecting one of the dropdown items. Below is my code:

```htmk
<template>
  <div class="relative bg-white">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between border-b-2 border-gray-100 py-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
        <div as="nav" class="hidden space-x-10 md:flex">
          <div class="relative">
            <button @click="openList" :class="[open ? 'text-gray-900' : 'text-gray-500', 'group inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-white text-base font-medium hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2']">
              <span>Analytics</span>
              <ChevronDownIcon :class="[open ? 'text-gray-600' : 'text-gray-400', 'ml-2 h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-gray-500']" aria-hidden="true" />
            </button>
            <transition v-if="listIsVisible" enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-200" enter-from-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1" enter-to-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-150" leave-from-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" leave-to-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1">
              <div class="absolute z-10 -ml-4 mt-3 w-screen max-w-md transform px-2 sm:px-0 lg:left-1/2 lg:ml-0 lg:-translate-x-1/2">
                <div class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5">
                  <div class="relative grid gap-6 bg-white px-5 py-6 sm:gap-8 sm:p-8">

                      <div class="ml-4">
                        <a href="/kgaps">
                          <p class="justify-end text-base font-medium text-gray-900 ml-2">Contract Gaps</p>
                          <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 ml-2">Learn where there are gaps in contracts.</p>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/ftm">
                          <p class="justify-end text-base font-medium text-gray-900 ml-2 mt-6">FTM</p>
                          <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 ml-2">Look at the massive amount of information this dashboard has.</p>
                        </a>
                        <subscriptions-modal>
                        </subscriptions-modal>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </transition>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/20/solid'
import SubscriptionsModal from './SubscriptionsModal'
const listIsVisible = ref(false);
function openList() {
    listIsVisible.value = !listIsVisible.value
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code contains much code that is totally unrelated to the problem, and this can make it hard for us to be able to separate the important code from the filler. Please consider simplifying the code to a [mre] -- minimal code required to run and reproduce the problem and nothing more. Please read the link as it well explains what it is I'm recommending and how it can help both you and us.

Comment: Apologies, I've now updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the drop-down close from any click on this template by adding another @click on an outer element, one that calls a function that closes the drop-down list, e.g.,

```
<template>
    <div @click="closeList" class="relative bg-white">
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between border-b-2 border-gray-100 py-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
          <div as="nav" class="hidden space-x-10 md:flex">
            <!-- ... etc ...  -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

And then giving your script section a function that does just this:

```
function closeList() {
   listIsVisible.value = false;
}
```

But for this work you will need to block event propagation in the original button click to prevent `closeList()` from being called after `openList()` has been called. And so this:

```html
<button @click="openList" :class=....>
```

will need to be changed to this:

```html
<button @click.stop="openList" :class=....>
```

adding a `@click.stop` to prevent propagation along the event chain.

---

Also, if you need to have a parent component also trigger the `closeList()` function, then you could trigger the function by any of the usual ways, including using refs, or an event bus, or props with a watcher,....

---

Also, another option is to respond to an element's loss of focus using the `onfocusout` JavaScript event:

```html
<button @click.stop="openList" @focusout="closeList" ...
```

Doing this would allow you to not have to use @click elsewhere in a component to close the list and would avoid your having to change the code of your parent component.

---

Regarding how to use watchers with the Composition API, there are several tutorials that explain this well, including and especially [this one from the Vue.js documentation pages](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html). If you are still having errors when trying to use these, then you may want to write a new question.

Comment: Thank you, that did work. However, due to how I will eventually break up my code I will have to trigger the closeList click in my App.vue. I apologize for the many questions, as I've been using options API and just switched to comp. recently, how would I use props with a watcher? The ways in which I've tried I get error messages each time trying to code it.

Comment: @ironman33: I completely forgot about the `onfocusout` event which would fix the problem of having to change the parent elements' code. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: Thank you @Hovercraft Full of Eels! That worked!